# Getting a file size mismatch with android download code

Tags: android

I'm downloading a file from a server and for some reason i can't determine, the downloaded file size doesn't match the original file size. Here's my code.

```
private class dl extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Void>
{
    int size;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            URL myFileUrl = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8080/testdlapps/chrome-beta.zip");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        conn.connect();

        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

        size = conn.getContentLength();
        Log.v("INFO---------------------", "size is " +size);

        FileOutputStream fout1 = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"xyz.zip");
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fout1);

        byte[] b = new byte[1024]; int  i=0, count=0;
        while((count = is.read(b)) != -1)
        {
            bos.write(b,0,count); 
            i+=count;
            publishProgress(i);
            Log.v("INFO----------------------------",""+count);
        }
        fout1.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.v("INFO--------------------------","Error!!");
            Log.v("INFO--------------------------",e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        tv.setText("downloaded " + progress[0] + "/" + size ); //tv is a TextView
     }
}
```

When i run the app, after the download completes, count and size are the same but the actual file size i.e /mnt/sdcard/xyz.zip is always less than size. Any ideas what going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

override onPostExecute and check if actually it finishes, perhaps here a code to download with resume support,
pay attention because if you press back the download may still run:

```
if (isCancelled())
    return false;
```

in the loop is needed because the close() on the socket will hang on exit without you noticeing it

here is the code:

```
class DownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>
{
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;
    private Context mContext;
    private Long mFileSize;
    private Long mDownloaded;
    private String mDestFile;

    public DownloaderTask(Context context, String path)
    {
        mContext = context;
        mFileSize = 1L;
        mDownloaded = 0L;
        mDestFile = path;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        mProgress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgress.setMessage("Downloading...");
        mProgress.setCancelable(true);
        mProgress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        mProgress.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)
            {
                DownloaderTask.this.cancel(true);
            }
        });
        mProgress.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... percent)
    {
        mProgress.setProgress(percent[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        BufferedInputStream in = null;
        BufferedOutputStream out = null;
        AndroidHttpClient mClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("AndroidDownloader");

        try
        {

            HttpResponse response = null;

            HttpHead head = new HttpHead(urls[0]);
            response = mClient.execute(head);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK)
                return false;

            Boolean resumable = response.getLastHeader("Accept-Ranges").getValue().equals("bytes");

            File file = new File(mDestFile);
            mFileSize = (long) Integer.parseInt(response.getLastHeader("Content-Length").getValue());

            mDownloaded = file.length();

            if (!resumable || (mDownloaded >= mFileSize))
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "Invalid size / Non resumable - removing file");
                file.delete();
                mDownloaded = 0L;
            }

            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(urls[0]);

            if (mDownloaded > 0)
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "Resume download from " + mDownloaded);
                get.setHeader("Range", "bytes=" + mDownloaded + "-");
            }

            response = mClient.execute(get);
            if ((response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK) && (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_PARTIAL_CONTENT))
                return false;

            if (mDownloaded > 0)
                publishProgress((int) ((mDownloaded / mFileSize) * 100));

            in = new BufferedInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent());
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            int n = 0;
            while ((n = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1)
            {
                if (isCancelled())
                    return false;

                out.write(buffer, 0, n);
                mDownloaded += n;
                publishProgress((int) ((mDownloaded / (float) mFileSize) * 100));
            }

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } finally
        {
            try
            {
                mClient.close();
                if (in != null)
                    in.close();
                if (out != null)
                    out.close();
                if (fos != null)
                    fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled()
    {
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
    {
        if (mProgress.isShowing())
            mProgress.dismiss();

        if (result)
            // done
        else
            // error
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but it wont be compatible with devices with android os older than froyo (yes i was shocked also when i discovered that it was part of the requirements). AndroidHttpClient is only valid for 2.2+

Comment: the suggestion about the onPostExecute should be still valid

Answer (score 0):

If it is a chunked response, the content-length in the header will be a guess at best.

Comment: But in this case the content-length header is always correct.